# Set $_SESSION to two URLs/Domains

Tags: php, session

is it possible to have a set $_SESSION available over two URLS/Domains? Ultimately they are the same Im using .htaccess to re-write a part of the domain:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}                  ^pagefor\.local$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z0-9-.]+)$       http://pagefor/$1.local [L,R]

RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z0-9-.]+).local$       index.php?site=$1 [NC,L]
```

The above Rewrites the URL if the following occurs `http://pagefor.local/{USERNAME}` to `http://pagefor/{USERNAME}.local`. This all works fine, although when a $_SESSION is set on `http://pagefor.local` the same $_SESSION is not available on `http://pagefor/{USERNAME}.local`.

I thought the $_SESSION would be available to both, seeing as its the same domain? What would be the most effective way to get the $_SESSION set for both? Thankyou

Answer (score 0):

PHP sessions rely on cookies (PHPSESSID cookie in particular). Cookies are assigned to a domain name, which means your browser will not reveal cookie set by one domain to another.

Comment: Surely there must be a way for $_SESSION to be set to be available over two domains?